# TypeError: Cannot read property 'vote' of null in render view

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spfx

In this component I get a Promise object in the properties, I try to put it in state, but when the view is rendered, I get the message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'vote' of null", asking for a solution to my problem, I spent two hours on it and I don't see the end. What should I do differently?

```
    import { IVoteDetailsProps } from "./IVoteDetailsProps";
    import { IVoteDetailsState } from "./IVoteDetailsState";

   export class VoteDetails extends React.Component<IVoteDetailsProps, IVoteDetailsState>{
    constructor(props: IVoteDetailsProps) {
    super();
    console.log(props)

}
componentDidMount() {
    let data = this.props.voteDetails;
    data.then(result => this.setState({
        vote: result
    }));
};
public render(): React.ReactElement<IVoteDetailsState> {
    return (
        <table >
            <tbody>                    
                {this.state.vote && this.state.vote.map(el => {

                    <tr id={el.id.toString()}>
                        <td>{el.title}</td>
                        <td>{el.voteType}</td>
                    </tr>

                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>

    )
  }
}
```

```
    export interface IVoteDetailsProps {
        voteDetails: Promise<IVoteDetailsData[]>;
    }
```

```
export interface IVoteDetailsData{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    voteType: string;
}
```

```
import React = require("react");
import { VoteDetails } from "../VoteDetails/VoteDetails";
import { IVoteListProps } from "./IVoteListProps";


export class VoteList extends React.Component<IVoteListProps, {}> {

    constructor(props: IVoteListProps) {
        super(props);     
        console.log(props)
    }

    public render(): React.ReactElement<IVoteListProps> {
        // const { vote } = this.state;
        return (
            <VoteDetails  voteDetails={this.props.adminServicePanel.getVotesInfo()}  />
        )
    };
}
```

```
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IVoteSecurityAppProps> {
    return (
      <main className="ui main text container">
      <VoteList adminServicePanel={this.props.adminPanelService}/>
    </main>

    );
```

```
import {HttpClient}  from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import { reject } from 'lodash';
import {IAdminPanelService} from './IAdminPanelService';
import {IReportData} from './IReportData'
import { IVoteDetailsData } from './IVoteDetailsData';
import {IVoteInfo} from './IVoteInfo'
import {VoteOptions} from './VoteOptions';
export class AdminPanelService implements IAdminPanelService {
    
    //////////////////////////////MOCK////////////////////////////////////////////
    private voteInfos : IVoteDetailsData[];
    private reportData : IReportData[];
//////////////////////////////MOCK////////////////////////////////////////////



    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private serverRelativeSiteUrl: string) {
        //MOCK
        this.voteInfos = [
            {
                id : 1,
                title : "xxx",
                voteType : "xx"

            },
            {
                id : 2,
                title : "xxx",
                voteType : "xxx"
            }

        ];
    }

    public getVotesInfo () : Promise<IVoteDetailsData[]> {
        return new Promise<IVoteDetailsData[]>((resolve : (voteMiniInfo : IVoteDetailsData[]) => void, reject : (error: any) => void): void =>{
         
            resolve(this.voteInfos);
        })

    }

}
```

```
export interface IAdminPanelService {
    getVotesInfo:() => Promise<IVoteDetailsData[]>;
}
```

Comment: threr are no vote  in state

Comment: Firstly, I don't understand why you use a promise instead of the real value ? could you explain to me ?

Comment: someday this data will be downloaded from api so I decided that now I will start writing  the promise

Comment: You could simplify this by using `async` and `await`.

Comment: Okay okay, I am reading your code can I see the code where you pass the adminPanelService to the VoteListt ? I mea the parent of this component rendering the VoteList. I have to see something

Comment: I put a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './VoteSecurityApp.module.scss';
import { IVoteSecurityAppProps } from './IVoteSecurityAppProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { VoteList } from './VoteList/VoteList';

export default class VoteSecurityApp extends React.Component<IVoteSecurityAppProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IVoteSecurityAppProps> {
    return (
      <main className="ui main text container">
      <VoteList adminServicePanel={this.props.adminPanelService}/>
    </main>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class VoteDetails extends React.Component<IVoteDetailsProps, IVoteDetailsState> 
{

    state = {
        vote: null,
    }

// change this
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.voteDetails().then(result => this.setState({
        vote: result
    }));
};

    // rest of your codes here

}

export class VoteList extends React.Component<IVoteListProps, {}> {

    constructor(props: IVoteListProps) {
        super(props);     
        console.log(props)
    }

    public render(): React.ReactElement<IVoteListProps> {
        // const { vote } = this.state;
        return (
            <VoteDetails  voteDetails= 
                     {this.props.adminServicePanel.getVotesInfo}  /> // change this line
        )
    };
}
```

Comment: it does not solve the problem, there is no error but the data is empty which is not good

Comment: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of nul"

Answer (score 0):

All errors "TypeError: Cannot read property '......' of null" in spfx components, when you call

> this.state.{varname}

or

> this.props.{varname}

solves one of:

1. Add binding 'this' in constructor to method where rise error

> this.{methodname} = this.{methodname}.bind(this)

2. You miss initialize state in constructor (for React.Component<props,state>)

> this.state = {};

3. You use value from props or state and miss check it for null

In question I see all of this things. For example, in this peice of code state will not be initialized, otherwise component has state

```
export class VoteDetails extends React.Component<IVoteDetailsProps, IVoteDetailsState>{
    constructor(props: IVoteListProps) {
            super(props);     
            console.log(props)
            //this.state == null - true
        }
}
```

Second problem is this code

```
<VoteDetails  voteDetails={this.props.adminServicePanel.getVotesInfo()}
```

getVotesInfo- return promise, not data. This bad practice, use state to hold data, for example

```
constructor(props: ...){
  super(props);
  this.state{
    data: null
  };
  this._getData = this._getData.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(){
  this._getData();
}

async _getData(){
  if(this.props.adminServicePanel){
    let data = await this.props.adminServicePanel.getVotesInfo();
    this.setStae({data});
  }
}

render():...{
  const data = this.state.data;
  return(
  {data && data.map(...)}
  );
}
```